# Windows Store unhandled exceptions on TP threads don't crash the app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, async-await

I have an async method that is throwing. This has no impact on my app, I see the exception in the debugger output window.

I can turn on first chance exceptions and have the VS debugger catch it in the expected place, i.e. when the call returns at the `await` keyword.

However, I'd expect this exception to crash my app.

> Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0, the common language
>   runtime allows most unhandled exceptions in threads to proceed
>   naturally. In most cases this means that the unhandled exception
>   causes the application to terminate.

Why doesn't it? -- I have found the answer so I'll post Q/A style to keep it useful for others.

Comment: Some good stuff in those dupe links, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is that I am several calls deep from an `async void`. The exception is being caught and placed into the `Task` that's returned from the current asynchronous method and that process occurs for each asynchronous call up the stack.

The problem comes when it reaches `async void`, there's no `Task` object through which exceptions can be marshalled back to the main process thread. Hence it is swallowed.

Given that due to the event-driven nature of UI work, its common to have an `async void` at the top of the stack and so this is a gotcha that's going to be hit a fair few times.

From now on, I'll ensure I wrap a `try catch` around code inside event handlers.

http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-async-gotchas.aspx/